# Is there any other validators similar to validity.valid

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, angular-material

I am looking for a simple validation setup that can validate a form field based on pattern, `minlength, maxlength` and validity. I came across this

`onInput = "validity.valid || (valid='')"`.

Can I use this to match a pattern. The code looks simple enough for a quick use.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do recommendations. Do note that HTML5 provides interfaces for all of those: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: I was looking for a sample of validating a pattern. After angular v6, using ngModel and formControl was deprecated. So I am unable to use that.

Comment: [Edit] your question to make it clear what you are looking for.